# Synonym request [jquery-dialog] -> [jquery-ui-dialog]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, synonym-request

Here's another synonym request in the spirit of my last one. [jquery-ui-dialog](/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-dialog) and [jquery-dialog](/questions/tagged/jquery-dialog) refer to the same component. The former has about 1200 questions, and the latter 300. Per the "jquery-ui-" naming scheme the tags should be merged as [jquery-ui-dialog](/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-dialog).

Comment: The [synonym suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui-dialog/synonyms)  has been [created](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327296/help-clean-up-jquery-ui-tags#comment363685_327296) and it needs upvotes